# Metaboxes inside Tab

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, metabox, admin-menu, tabs

I am learning WordPress Plugin development. In this regard I have to save some settings along with Custom Post in Admin Panel under a Menu. Can I place metaboxes inside tab for this issue like the below image ?

[image]

Comment: Metaboxes are used for storing additional data along with the post. What you are looking for is a Menu/Sub Menu Page. And, yes, you can create tabs within the menu page. Have a look at the [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/).

Comment: Thanks @Abhik. Yes, I would like to store additional data along with the post. How can I create a Custom Form with Tabs to save Metabox data ? Thanks.

Comment: This is where you start. [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)